# Statistical test for comparison of counts for 2 groups where requirements for Chi-Square test are not met

Tags: chi-squared-test, count-data, fishers-exact-test

I would like to compare overall codon counts in the yeast genome with codon counts from an individual sequence. The totals for the 2 groups are not the same.

I cannot use a chi-square test, since when I scale my expected values to my observed values, most of the counts are less than 5. As far as I know, I can't do Fisher's exact test, since my table is larger than 2x2.

What are some alternatives to the chi-square test? I would like to run the test on Python, if possible.

Below is a sample of my data (only includes 8 codons, but the full dataset has 61).

[image: sample of data]

Comment: (1) Applicability of the chi-squared test is assessed based on *expected* counts, not counts. (2) Fisher's Exact test works for $n\times 2$ tables, too--but can require much more RAM to carry out precisely. (3) The rule of thumb that most cells should have expectations of 5 or larger doesn't apply to tables with large numbers of cells.

Comment: @whuber I didn't include this in the sample data, but before running the chi-square test, I scale my expected values to my observed values. In other words, I'm doing this calculation:

expected_scaled = expected / (sum of all expected values) * (sum of all observed values)

Are there any requirements for tables with large numbers of cells? And is there a good reference on that?

Comment: That scaling step will destroy the test.  An alternative to consider is a Poisson GLM (a logistic regression).  It will approximate the slightly more correct Binomial GLM extremely well.